# What does "Logical database name" field refer to on Data Source page of an AppSync API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-serverless, amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora MySql 5.6 serverless database configured and I am trying to set up an AppSync API with a data source to connect this database.

On the AppSync "Data Sources" page, I have "Relational database" selected as Data source type. The page also has a "Logical database name" field and I do not know what to enter there. What goes into this field? Is it arbitrary or it must match some value from my Aurora configuration?

Answer (score 0):

AWS AppSync uses the Data API that you can use to front a Aurora Serverless MySQL cluster. The logical database name corresponding to a MySQL database. You can see the databases you have in your cluster by running show databases on your cluster.